# slide tab panels in left and out right

Tags: jquery

I have three panels and three buttons and am trying to achieve the following action:

<--- 1, 2, 3, --->

- If panel 1 is in view and you click 2: panel 1 slides out of view to the left
  and panel 2 comes into view from the right
- If panel 2 is in view and you click 1: panel 2 slides out to the right and panel 1 comes into view from the left.
- If panel 3 is in view and you click 2: panel 3 slides out to the right and panel 2 comes into view from the left.

etc. etc.

This is the jQuery I have been trying:

```
var tabs = $('#panels>li');

$('.tab').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_tab = tabs.eq($(this).index()).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
  tabs.not(current_tab).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
$(".tab:first").click();
});
```

This works fine if I just use `.show()` and `.hide()`, but if I try to add the slide animation (`"slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000`) it breaks (the panels do not appear).... Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The hTML:

```
<div class="tab">1</div>
<div class="tab">2</div>
<div class="tab">3</div>

<ul id="panels">
 <li>Panel 1</li>
 <li>Panel 2</li>
 <li>Panel 3</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#panels > li {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/VgXK4/21/

**jQuery:**

```
var panels = $('ul#panels li');
panels.css('left','-500px').first().css('left','0px');

$('.tab').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).index();
    panels.each(function(i){
        if( i != target) { $(this).stop().animate({'left':'-500px'},1000); }
        //hides all other
        else{ $(this).stop().animate({'left':'0px'},1000); }
        //shows matched ele
    });
});​
```

**css:**

```
ul#panels { position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:500px; }
    ul#panels li { position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; }
```